# How to unhide drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I have tried everything, searched for how to unhide the drive but nothing worked. Drive C has its drive #,letter and label as shown in cmd but it does not appear in the explorer/my computer.

[image: img of explorer]

[image: img of cmd prompt]

Comment: We cannot help you because you have tried everything so there's nothing left to try. Seriously: what exactly have you tried?

Comment: You talking about which drive?  which drives letter are visible in Explorer and which not?

Comment: I have added the img. Its C.

Comment: According to the `list volume` command your C is a system reserved volume and is hidden as expected. If you need to reclaim your letter you can use the disk manager. `cmd > diskmgmt.msc`

Comment: You really don't want to be using letters A or B either; they're legacy floppy disk allocations. Also, what you you think your are gaining by partitioning into lots of small volumes? One for Pagefile??

Comment: You can hide a drive through group policies. start `gpedit.msc` to access it.

Answer (score -1):

1. Start Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc) on your computer and take a closer look at your hard disk. Note the disk number and the partitions.
2. Start DiskPart and select your disk: DISKPART> `select disk 0`
3. List all partitions: DISKPART> `list partition`
4. Now, select the hidden partition DISKPART> `select partition 3` (Make sure its your C drive)
5. DISKPART> `detail partition` and verify that it is hidden. 
   [image]

**Detail Parition Gives you detail of Partition as image mentioned below**
Let me know the Type number:

Comment: -1 because OP already shows in their screenshot that the disk is not hidden and has a driveletter.

Comment: I wanted know about type number. We had same issue in our lab it was showing the hidden in details and letter was visible.